# Will a click counter slow down my DynamoDB API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to create a DynamoDB WebAPI. It allows the creation and reading of Posts. Now I would like to implement a click counter that updates the popularity of a post each time a user requests it. For this reason, every time a GET request for a posts comes in, I would change the Post object itself.
But I know that DynamoDB is optimized for reads, not for writes. So updating the object that is being fetched everytime would probably be a problem.
So how can I measure the popularity of posts without slowing down the API itself? I was thinking of generating a random number for every fetch and only updating it if it is below 0.05 or something similar.
But is there a better solution for this?

Comment: I think another service could be used to implement a hit count service. Counter information should not necessarily be stored in the same database as the data itself. For example one could use a relational database solution to store counter data. If using DynamoDB is a mandatory requirement then an alternative solution could be to trigger the hit count update asynchronously after returning the requested post.

Comment: Aren't relational databases slower than DynamoDB?

Comment: Might be slower, depending on the use-case and concurrency control. However, my point was that managing hit count counters should be done by a separate service, preferrably backed by a separate storage solution, updated asynchronously.

Comment: ok, thnkas that makes sense. But why should I use a seperate storage solution? Why not just create another table in dynamoDB?

Comment: By separate storage solution I meant an entity/record that is separate from the original entity/record stored. So a separate table should also work. Separation is required to not block record read requests by hit count write requests. Sorry, that was a bad choice of words on my part.

Comment: no problem, I get it now, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamo DB isn't "optimized for reads" it's optimized to provide "consistent, single-digit millisecond response times at any scale."

To optimize DDB for reads, you'd want to stick a Amazon DynamoDB Accelerator (DAX) instance in front of it for "faster access with microsecond latency".

In actuality, the DDB read/write performance isn't going to be an issue.  In your case the network latency between your app and DDB will be orders of magnitude higher. By making two calls synchronously one after the other you'd be doubling your response time; regardless of what cloud DB you're writing too.

Assuming the data and counter are in the same record, the simple DDB solution in this case would be to not make a call to `GetItem()` and one to `UpdateItem()`.  Instead, simply call `UpdateItem()` with an `UpdateExpression` that uses the `ADD` expression to add 1 to your counter and the `ReturnValues` attribute to return either `ALL_OLD` or `ALL_NEW`.

Other more complex solutions

- assuming you've already got the data for display, do an async call to UpdateItem().
- At scale, you might consider disconnecting the counter update from your app.  Your app post a SQS message, that's processed by a lambda which could use batch updates to DDB.

Comment: by App, do you mean the backend lambda code or the website js code?